# Allow Driver to Stop in Windows?

Tags: winapi, driver

Some drivers on Windows, like `Null` and  `Beep`, can be arbitrarily stopped and re-started through the `ControlService(..., SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, ...)` operation. Most other drivers, however, cannot be stopped and restarted while the system is running.

I'm making my own driver. How can I tell Windows that my driver can be stopped?

Comment: I think it's a flag in the CurrentControlSet registry branch corresponding to your driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you need to add a `DriverUnload` function:

```
VOID NTAPI DriverUnload(IN DRIVER_OBJECT *DriverObject) { }

NTSTATUS NTAPI DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
                           IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload; // <--- add this
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, **this is only sufficient if you're linking with `/DRIVER`**.
If you're linking with `/DRIVER:WDM` (meaning that `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_WDM_DRIVER` is set in the `DllCharacteristics` field) then it seems like this isn't sufficient. I think you may need to do more things, like handling IRPs as well. So check that too.

Comment: Hi I am doing kind of similar thing. Could you please paste your call to CreateService? I have the unload routine but whenever I call ControlService to stop it, it just changes from stoppable to unstoppable without actualy calling the unload routine.

Comment: @stupid_idiot: I don't remember where I put the code unfortunately. But it sounds like a problem with the driver itself, not with the call to `CreateService`.