# driver can't start at the second time

Tags: c++, windows, driver, wdk

I started to program driver. I red a lot articles and developed a test driver that's also working. At the beginnning it is just a Hello World Driver.
In a Console I install the driver, start and then stoped and remove. All is working well.
Just when I want to install and start it again, it returns Error no 2 at the function "StartService". Throught Debug-Message I can see that in the second time, the function DriverEntry is not called. 
But when I restard the PC then I can install and start the driver.
Unfurtunaly I could not find any articles about this problems. Just other problem which return 2 i.e. Driver not found. But all this is working.

I install the driver with:

```
    SC_HANDLE hSCManager;
SC_HANDLE hService;
SERVICE_STATUS ss;

hSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);

printf("Load Driver\n");

if(hSCManager)
{
    printf("Create Service\n");
    getchar();

    hService = CreateService(hSCManager, TEXT("Example"), TEXT("Example Driver"), SERVICE_START | DELETE | SERVICE_STOP, SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_DEMAND_START, SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE, TEXT("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\MyFirstDriver.sys"), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    //hService = CreateService(hSCManager, TEXT("Example"), TEXT("Example Driver"), SERVICE_START | DELETE | SERVICE_STOP, SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_DEMAND_START, SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE, TEXT("C:\\driver\\temp2\MyFirstDriver.sys"), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if(!hService)
    {
        printf("OpenService Service\n");
        getchar();
        hService = OpenService(hSCManager, TEXT("Example"), SERVICE_START | DELETE | SERVICE_STOP);
    }

    if(hService)
    {
        printf("Start Service\n");
        getchar();
        if (StartService(hService, 0, NULL))
        {
            printf("Start war erfolgreich\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Fehler beim starten\n");
            printf("StartService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 

        }

        Sleep(5000);
        printf("Press Enter to close service\n");
        getchar();
        printf("beendet\n");
        getchar();
        ControlService(hService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &ss);



        if (DeleteService(hService)) {
            printf("Delete war erfolgreich\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Fehler beim Delete\n");
            printf("Delete failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 
            //Error nr 6
        }

        if (CloseServiceHandle(hService)) {
            printf("Close war erfolgreich\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Fehler beim Close\n");
            printf("Close failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 

        }
    }
    printf("Press Enter to close service\n");
        getchar();
    CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
}
return 0;
```

The Code of the driver:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "functions.h"

void MyFirstDriverUnload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject);
NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverCreate(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp);
NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverClose(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp);
NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverDefaultHandler(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp);
NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverAddDevice(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject, IN PDEVICE_OBJECT  PhysicalDeviceObject);
NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverPnP(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp);
NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverRead(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp);
NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverUnsupportedFunc(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp);


typedef struct _deviceExtension
{
PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject;
PDEVICE_OBJECT TargetDeviceObject;
PDEVICE_OBJECT PhysicalDeviceObject;
UNICODE_STRING DeviceInterface;
} MyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION, *PMyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION;

// {282b517a-9a95-4fdc-8167-aec5f8463df3}
static const GUID GUID_MyFirstDriverInterface = {0x282B517A, 0x9a95, 0x4fdc, {0x81, 0x67, 0xae, 0xc5, 0xf8, 0x46, 0x3d, 0xf3 } };

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING  RegistryPath);
#endif

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING  RegistryPath)
{

DbgPrint("DriverEntry01 Called \r\n");
NTSTATUS NtStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    INT uiIndex = 0;
DbgPrint("DriverEntry02 Called \r\n");
    PDEVICE_OBJECT pDeviceObject = NULL;
DbgPrint("DriverEntry03 Called \r\n");
    UNICODE_STRING usDriverName, usDosDeviceName;

DbgPrint("DriverEntry3 Called \r\n");
DbgPrint("DriverEntry4 Called \r\n");
DbgPrint("DriverEntry5 Called \r\n");
    DbgPrint("DriverEntry6 Called \r\n");

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&usDriverName, L"\\Device\\Example");
DbgPrint("DriverEntry7 Called \r\n");
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&usDosDeviceName, L"\\DosDevices\\Example"); 
DbgPrint("DriverEntry8 Called \r\n");

    NtStatus = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, 0, &usDriverName, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &pDeviceObject);
DbgPrint("DriverEntry9 Called \r\n");
if(NtStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
    DbgPrint("DriverEntry10 Called \r\n");

    for(uiIndex = 0; uiIndex < IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION; uiIndex++)
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[uiIndex] = MyFirstDriverUnsupportedFunc;

        DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE]             = MyFirstDriverClose;
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE]            = MyFirstDriverCreate;
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_PNP]    = MyFirstDriverPnP;
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ]              = MyFirstDriverRead;

        DriverObject->DriverUnload =  MyFirstDriverUnload; 


        DriverObject->Flags &= (~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING);


        IoCreateSymbolicLink(&usDosDeviceName, &usDriverName);
    }


    return NtStatus;


}



void MyFirstDriverUnload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
DbgPrint("Goodbye from MyFirstDriver!\n");
}


NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverUnsupportedFunc(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
    NTSTATUS NtStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    DbgPrint("MyFirstDriverUnsupportedFunc \r\n");

    return NtStatus;
}

NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverRead(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
    NTSTATUS NtStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;


    DbgPrint("Example Read Called \r\n");

    return NtStatus;
}

NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverClose(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
NTSTATUS NtStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    DbgPrint("Drive Close \r\n");

    return NtStatus;
}

NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverCreate(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverDefaultHandler(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{

PMyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION deviceExtension = NULL;

IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
deviceExtension = (PMyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION) DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;
return IoCallDriver(deviceExtension->TargetDeviceObject, Irp);

}

NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverAddDevice(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject, IN PDEVICE_OBJECT  PhysicalDeviceObject)
{
PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject = NULL;
PMyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION pExtension = NULL;
NTSTATUS status;

status = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject,
                        sizeof(MyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION),
                        NULL,
                        FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN,
                        0,
                        0,
                        &DeviceObject);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    return status;

pExtension = (PMyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION)DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;

pExtension->DeviceObject = DeviceObject;
pExtension->PhysicalDeviceObject = PhysicalDeviceObject;
pExtension->TargetDeviceObject = IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStack(DeviceObject, PhysicalDeviceObject);

status = IoRegisterDeviceInterface(PhysicalDeviceObject, &GUID_MyFirstDriverInterface, NULL, &pExtension->DeviceInterface);
ASSERT(NT_SUCCESS(status));

DeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;
return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}


NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverIrpCompletion(
                  IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
                  IN PIRP Irp,
                  IN PVOID Context
                  )
{
PKEVENT Event = (PKEVENT) Context;

UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Irp);

KeSetEvent(Event, IO_NO_INCREMENT, FALSE);

return(STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED);
}

NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverForwardIrpSynchronous(
                          IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
                          IN PIRP Irp
                          )
{
PMyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION   deviceExtension;
KEVENT event;
NTSTATUS status;

KeInitializeEvent(&event, NotificationEvent, FALSE);
deviceExtension = (PMyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION) DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;

IoCopyCurrentIrpStackLocationToNext(Irp);

IoSetCompletionRoutine(Irp, MyFirstDriverIrpCompletion, &event, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);

status = IoCallDriver(deviceExtension->TargetDeviceObject, Irp);

if (status == STATUS_PENDING) {
    KeWaitForSingleObject(&event, Executive, KernelMode, FALSE, NULL);
    status = Irp->IoStatus.Status;
}
return status;
}

NTSTATUS MyFirstDriverPnP(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
PIO_STACK_LOCATION irpSp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
PMyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION pExt = ((PMyFirstDriver_DEVICE_EXTENSION)DeviceObject->DeviceExtension);
NTSTATUS status;

ASSERT(pExt);

switch (irpSp->MinorFunction)
{
case IRP_MN_START_DEVICE:
    IoSetDeviceInterfaceState(&pExt->DeviceInterface, TRUE);
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;

case IRP_MN_QUERY_REMOVE_DEVICE:
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;

case IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE:
    IoSetDeviceInterfaceState(&pExt->DeviceInterface, FALSE);
    status = MyFirstDriverForwardIrpSynchronous(DeviceObject, Irp);
    IoDetachDevice(pExt->TargetDeviceObject);
    IoDeleteDevice(pExt->DeviceObject);
    RtlFreeUnicodeString(&pExt->DeviceInterface);
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;

case IRP_MN_QUERY_PNP_DEVICE_STATE:
    status = MyFirstDriverForwardIrpSynchronous(DeviceObject, Irp);
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return status;
}
return MyFirstDriverDefaultHandler(DeviceObject, Irp);
}
```

Edit:
I tried the same with sc create and sc start. In the second time, it gives the error no 2 with the additional information that he can'T find the file.
But, as I said, the first time he can find the file and load. Second Time not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your driver containing huge count of errors and cannot be unloaded. you create Device `"\\Device\\Example"`in `DriverEntry` but you not delete it `MyFirstDriverUnload` - so this Device and hold driver from unloading. you try also be WDM driver, but i sure you not registered your driver as WDM for any deviceID and your `MyFirstDriverAddDevice` never called. WDM drivers (after you attach self device to device stack) at all can not be unloaded by start/stop but only after stop/destroying stack.

`DriverObject->Flags &= (~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING);`

else one error. about IRP handling i already not say. but again - in this concrete case driver not unloaded because you not call `IoDeleteDevice` in `MyFirstDriverUnload`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. As I wrote, I started to develop. So I will check this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: call IoDeleteDevice(pDeviceObject) in DriverUnload and fix this `DriverObject->Flags &= (~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING);` how minimum

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem isn't in starting the driver for the second time. But I don't know for sure: you don't check the return value of `ControlService(hService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &ss);`. My hypothesis is that [the driver can't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240515/allow-driver-to-stop-in-windows). Check the return value to see if the driver did stop, before trying to start it again.

Comment: Thanks, I checked. ControlService gives true back and on this time, the kernel debug shows "Goodbye driver" also my Debug message from the driver. Then I also tried to wait until the service stopped before it removed. But didn't helped